# CMake manage local dependecies

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two libraries `a` and `b`. The last depends on functions defined in the other (`a`).

When I link `a` to `b` it has no effect.

MWE on wsl2 with g++9 and cmake 3.16:

```
[...]

add_library(a ${a_SRC})
target_link_libraries(a CONAN_PKG::<foo>)

add_library(b ${b_SRC})
target_link_libraries(b a CONAN_PKG::<bar>)

add_executable(main ${main_SRC})
target_link_libraries(main a b)
```

I get an `undefined reference to` error. When I check the size of `libb.a` it is the same no matter if I link to `liba.a` or not in `target_link_libraries(b a CONAN_PKG::<bar>)`.

There is something I do not understand here!

I used an ugly workaround, where I include the source files of `a` in `b`:

```
[...]

add_library(a ${a_SRC})
target_link_libraries(a CONAN_PKG::<foo>)

add_library(b ${b_SRC} ${a_SRC})
target_link_libraries(b CONAN_PKG::<bar>)

add_executable(main ${main_SRC})
target_link_libraries(main a b)
```

Comment: Please provide the **specific** and complete error message. If the error is appearing during linking of `main`, it could simply be that your link order is incorrect (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)). You may need `target_link_libraries(main b a)` instead.

Comment: I tried both and it did not change the outcome!

Comment: The error message is `undefined reference to <function>` whith <function> being defined in `a.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is *still* not the **complete** error message, as it contains redacted information. Please copy/paste the *full* error message (as seen in this question [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574113/3987854)) with surrounding build logs to provide *context*. Without it, it is still unclear where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I misunderstood the issue I had.

In fact, `b` is a header-only library that depends on `a`.

The proper formulation is provided here:

[Linking a library to a header-only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689227/linking-a-library-to-a-header-only-one?noredirect=1#comment112624030_63689227)

Thanks to [squareskittles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854/squareskittles), for his comments.

Answer (score 0):

g++ (compared to MSVC) requires the correct order of linked libraries. If your `b` lib depends on `a`, than you should put it before `a` on the link list:

```
target_link_libraries(main b a)
```